# Is $(2x+ y) dx - xdy = 0$ a separable differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the following differential equation in an assignment the other day:

$(2x+ y) dx - xdy = 0$

The problem specified to solve the equation using the method of separation of variables. My problem was setting the integral, I tried multiple manipulations with but nothing seemed to work. So, I have to ask can this equation be solved using separation of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as

> $$ y'-y/x=2$$

then use the change of variables $y=xu\implies y'=xu'+u$ to transformed it to the separable ode

> $$xu'=2$$

which is the required method in the question!

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be rewritten as

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac 1xy=2$$

That means it is *not* a separable equation. However, it is a first-order linear ordinary differential equation, so it can be solve by the usual means. You will end up with at least one "special function" however, since part of the solution needs $\int e^{-1/x}\,dx$ which cannot be expressed in elementary functions.

Comment: "You will end up with at least one "special function" however, since part of the solution needs $\int e^{-1/x}\,dx$ which cannot be expressed in elementary functions." Actually they will not end up etc. and the solution does not need a primitive of $e^{-1/x}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an **exact** differential equation, since $$\frac{\partial(2x+y)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}.$$

**EDIT:**

The work: $$\Psi = f(y)+\int 2x+y\, dx$$ $$\Psi = x^2 + xy + f(y)$$ $$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y} = x + f'(y) = x$$ $$f'(y) = 0$$ $$f(y) = 0$$ $$\Psi = x^2 + xy$$ $$x^2+xy = C$$ $$y = \frac{C-x^2}{x}$$ Could anyone tell me why that solution doesn't work if you plug it in?